# Sort results by proximity with the "around" service in Wikidata

Tags: geospatial, wikidata, sparql

With this [query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fplace%20%3FplaceLabel%20%3Flocation%20WHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20wd%3AQ64%20wdt%3AP625%20%3FarcLoc%20.%20%0A%20%20%3Fplace%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ515%20.%0A%20%20%3Fplace%20wdt%3AP17%20wd%3AQ183%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Aaround%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fplace%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Flocation%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Acenter%20%3FarcLoc%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Aradius%20%2250%22%20.%20%0A%20%20%7D%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%20%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D), I can get a list of German cities around Berlin, within a radius of 50 km.

```
SELECT ?place ?placeLabel ?location WHERE
{
  wd:Q64 wdt:P625 ?arcLoc . 
  ?place wdt:P31 wd:Q515 .
  ?place wdt:P17 wd:Q183 .
  SERVICE wikibase:around { 
      ?place wdt:P625 ?location . 
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:center ?arcLoc . 
      bd:serviceParam wikibase:radius "50" . 
  } 
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . 
  }
}
```

How can I sort the result by proximity in Km, like it is done in [this page](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:Nearby)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ?place ?placeLabel ?location ?distance WHERE
    {
      wd:Q64 wdt:P625 ?arcLoc . 
      ?place wdt:P31 wd:Q515 .
      ?place wdt:P17 wd:Q183 .
      SERVICE wikibase:around { 
          ?place wdt:P625 ?location . 
          bd:serviceParam wikibase:center ?arcLoc . 
          bd:serviceParam wikibase:radius "50" . 
      } 
      SERVICE wikibase:label {
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" . 
      }
      BIND(geof:distance(?arcLoc, ?location) AS ?distance) 
    } ORDER BY ASC(?distance)
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fplace%20%3FplaceLabel%20%3Flocation%20%3Fdistance%20WHERE%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20wd%3AQ64%20wdt%3AP625%20%3FarcLoc%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fplace%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ515%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fplace%20wdt%3AP17%20wd%3AQ183%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Aaround%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fplace%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Flocation%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Acenter%20%3FarcLoc%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Aradius%20%2250%22%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20BIND%28geof%3Adistance%28%3FarcLoc%2C%20%3Flocation%29%20AS%20%3Fdistance%29%20%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20ASC%28%3Fdistance%29%0A%0A)

---

P.S. `geof:` is for `<http://www.opengis.net/def/geosparql/function/>`.