# Filter wikidata results with 'around' service

Tags: geospatial, wikidata

Is it possible to use the "around" service as a filter, for example to search for a place name in a country and limit results to those within a given distance of a known point.

For example, limit results of the following search to those within 50km of

`"Point(-98.966111 19.310278)"^^geo:wktLiteral`

```
SELECT distinct ?item ?itemLabel ?countryLabel ?geom

WHERE { 
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }

  ?item rdfs:label "Santa Catarina"@en ;
   (wdt:P31/wdt:P279*) ?itemType ;
    wdt:P17 ?country .
    ?country rdfs:label "Mexico"@en .

  # human settlement | archaeological site  
  FILTER (?itemType = wd:Q486972 || ?itemType = wd:Q839954) .

  # coordinate location
  OPTIONAL {?item wdt:P625 ?geom . }
}
```

Comment: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries/examples#Items_geographically_located_around_the_Wikimedia_Foundation_office,_sorted_by_distance

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/11673/16193

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort results by proximity with the "around" service in Wikidata](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/11671/sort-results-by-proximity-with-the-around-service-in-wikidata)